# Error in CICD pipeline build while Deploying single project from multi-project .NET solution with Azure DevOps

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to build a single `cs` project from a multi-project .net solution using CICD, but it gives error in MSBuild. I am using `boilerplate`. Below are the steps of my pipeline:

[image: Pipeline]
[image: Get Source]
[image: NuGetRestore]
[image: Build Solution]

In build, I am getting some assembly reference errors like

```
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Abp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FullAuditedEntity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DependsOnAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DependsOn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AbpZeroCoreModule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AbpZeroLdapModule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILocalizableString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: If that project is a asp.net core project, I suggest you use [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) task instead of [nuget restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) task. Check the **Note** in Nuget task and you can see: `Using or creating .NET Core or .NET Standard packages? Use the .NET Core task, which has full support for all package scenarios currently supported by dotnet, including restore, pack, and nuget push.`

Answer (score 1):

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Abp' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'FullAuditedEntity' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)......

These errors indicate that the `boilerplate` related assemblies are not restored successfully. So your actual issue could come from the `nuget restore` step.

For this:

1.Make sure your project reference the `boilerplate` related assemblies by **nuget packages**(Boilerplate,Abp.AspNetCore...)

2.Check your log of `nuget restore task` and make sure you can see something like this:

[image]

If you can't see this message, try using `dotnet restore` task + `**/*.sln` to restore packages for your project.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Does those missing assemblies come from nuget.org or your devops feed? Maybe it's one issue about package source, could you share some details about the new errors you get in question? I will check it soon.

Comment: @ Lance Li-MSFT
 Now if i use dotnet restore task its giving some assemblies not found error

Comment: @user3099388 Does you solution contains both .net framework and .net core projects? If so, you need to use nuget restore for .net framework projects and dotnet restore for those .net core projects. (It means you can't use simple nuget restore or dotnet restore for whole solution).

Answer (score -1):

"D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\a\9\s{projectname}\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\a\9\s\ "

Restoring NuGet packages...
  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.

##[error].nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): Error : Unable to find version '3.19.6' of package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory'.
D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Unable to find version '3.19.6' of package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory'. [D:\a\9\s{projectname}{projectname}.csproj]

##[error].nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): Error : Unable to find version '2.0.12' of package 'Microsoft.PowerBI.Api'.
 D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Unable to find version '2.0.12' of package 'Microsoft.PowerBI.Api'. [D:\a\9\s{projectname}{projectname}.csproj]

##[error].nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): Error : Unable to find version '2.3.11' of package 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime'.
 D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Unable to find version '2.3.11' of package 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime'. [D:\a\9\s{projectname}{projectname}.csproj]

##[error].nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): Error : Unable to find version '1.7.0' of package 'System.Collections.Immutable'.
 D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Unable to find version '1.7.0' of package 'System.Collections.Immutable'. [D:\a\9\s{projectname}{projectname}.csproj]

##[error].nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): Error : Unable to find version '4.5.0' of package 'System.ValueTuple'.
 D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Unable to find version '4.5.0' of package 'System.ValueTuple'. [D:\a\9\s{projectname}{projectname}.csproj]

### [error].nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): Error MSB3073: The command ""D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.exe

" install "D:\a\9\s{projectname}\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\a\9\s\ "" exited with code 1.
 D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error MSB3073: The command ""D:\a\9\s.nuget\NuGet.exe"
 install "D:\a\9\s{projectname}\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\a\9\s\ "" exited with code 1. [D:\a\9\s{projectname}{projectname}.csproj]

Done Building Project "D:\a\9\s{projectname}{projectname}.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.